# Problem with Firebase Realtime DB pagination

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I would like to filter results by a certain child with `equalTo` but also want to paginate the results. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68697605/3930247) but I'm getting this error:

> startAfter: Starting point was already set (by another call to startAt, startAfter, or equalTo).

Checking the source code, it looks like `equalTo` basically sets both `startAt` and `endAt` and because I tried to set `startAt` *again*, it's erroring out.

Is it because of my Firebase Admin SDK version? I'm using v9.4.2.

Here's my code:

```js
query = query.orderByChild("category").equalTo(filter);

if (lastKey) {
  query = query.startAfter("", lastKey);
}
```

Comment: Answer below, but if that doesn't help enough, please edit your question to show the values of `filter` and `startAfter` and the JSON that you're querying.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated the question and I solved it, so I'll write down the answer myself.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the answer and also I think you need to update your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697334/pagination-for-firebase-realtime-database/68697605#68697605).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as I already said in the question, `equalTo` and `startAt` or `startAfter` cannot be used at the same time because `equalTo` under the hood calls both `startAt` and `endAt` with the same value.

Logically also, it doesn't make sense to find something that is "equal to some value *and* greater than another value".

So, my solution was to use `startAt` and `endAt` with the same filter value, but adding the `lastKey` value to the `startAt` clause so that it can paginate.

Here's my code:

```
query = query.orderByChild("category").startAt(filter, lastKey).endAt(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single `startAt`/`startAfter`/`equalTo` call in a query on the Firebase Realtime Database.

If your `startAfter` is a `category` value (i.e. the same value as `filter`, you're looking for:

```
query = query.orderByChild("category").startAt(startAfter).endAt(filter+'~');
```

If your `startAfter` is the **key** of a node with the same category as `filter`, then you're looking for:

```
query = query.orderByChild("category").startAt(filter, startAfter).endAt(filter+'~');
```

The `~` is not some magic operator, but just a character high in the ASCII range.